# Char Array to Lambda Expression

Tags: arrays, loops, java-8

I am now learning lambda expression used in Java.
In this case, I have a problem in changing char[] array to lambda expression.
So, I would like to ask some help.
My sample code is below.

```
    Map<String, String> tempMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    tempMap.put("a", "A");
    tempMap.put("b", "B");
    tempMap.put("c", "C");
    tempMap.put("d", "D");
    tempMap.put("e", "E");
    String tempStr = "abcdef";
    StringBuilder tempBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    char[] tempArray = tempStr.toCharArray();
    for(char c : tempArray) {
    tempBuilder.append(tempMap.getOrDefault(String.ValueOf(c),
    String.ValueOf(c));
    }
```

Result should be "ABCDEf". Thanks.

Comment: Well, first of all, you never never do a tempMap.put() for "f" and "F". More importantly, though, you told us what your expected result is but you didn't tell us your actual result.

Comment: It's a little unclear to me where you're trying to use a lambda expression here. Are you asking how to do this with streams?

Comment: Yes, I would like to used it with streams.

Comment: If each letter of input string does not include in map, it doesn't change.So, result is "ABCDEf" because there is not "f" in map. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Stream.of('a','b','c','d','e','f')
      .map(String::valueOf)
      .map(c -> tempMap.getOrDefault(c,c))
      .forEach(tempBuilder::append);
```

Do you mean using stream like this?

Comment: Input is string and may vary. Direct input in Stream is not ok. Firstly, I would like to change tempStr to char[] array and then loop char[] array. Thanks.

Comment: The answer from @4casle is better than this. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`CharSequence#codePoints`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#codePoints--) to create a stream of characters (which is more surrogate-pair safe than `chars`), make your transformations, and then use [`Collectors.joining()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining--).

```
String input = "abcdef";
String output = input.codePoints()
                     .mapToObj(Character::toChars)
                     .map(String::valueOf)
                     .map(s -> tempMap.getOrDefault(s, s))
                     .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Comment: Yes. But I don't like to use collect(Collectors.joining()); for better performance. Thanks.

Comment: @H_M I've not benchmarked the performance difference, but it uses a `StringBuilder` internally as well, and also supports parallelization.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to [4castle’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43083929/2711488) is

```
String output = Pattern.compile("").splitAsStream(tempStr)
                       .map(s -> tempMap.getOrDefault(s, s))
                       .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

This doesn’t handle characters outside the BMP, but as long as you’re note using them as keys in the `Map`, the surrogate pairs will be correctly assembled to their original form in the result string, like in you original `char[]` approach.

If you want to support characters outside the BMP, you can use

```
String output = Pattern.compile("(?!\\p{Cs})").splitAsStream(tempStr)
                       .map(s -> tempMap.getOrDefault(s, s))
                       .collect(Collectors.joining());
```